# Pinotdb: DatabaseError: timed out: Out of -1, only -1 responded, while needed was -1

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-eks, apache-pinot

I'm working with Pinotdb library for python and I want to query my database sample.
I can see the UI and see the tables, now I want to code it.

[image]

I have pinot installed in an AWS EKS cluster, and I exposed port 9000 and 8099 for services pinot-controller and pinot-broker.

I have a simple code following the documentation [link](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/users/clients/python) but It always gives me this error:

```json
{
  "errorMessage": "Query\n\n{'sql': 'select * from testing limit 10'} timed out: Out of -1, only -1 responded, while needed was -1",
  "errorType": "DatabaseError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 13, in lambda_handler\n    cursor.execute(query)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pinotdb/db.py\", line 57, in g\n    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pinotdb/db.py\", line 492, in execute\n    return self.normalize_query_response(query, r)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pinotdb/db.py\", line 411, in normalize_query_response\n    input_query, num_servers_queried, num_servers_responded\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pinotdb/db.py\", line 368, in check_sufficient_responded\n    f\"Query\\n\\n{query} timed out: Out of {queried}, only\"\n"
  ]
}
```

My code is:

```py
from pinotdb import connect

hosted='MyHost/'


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    connection = connect(host=hosted, port=9000, scheme='http', timeout=50)
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    # Execute a select
    query = "select * from testing limit 10"
    cursor.execute(query)
```

I already try with all the ports that my services have:

```
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
pinot-broker                ClusterIP   IP               <none>        8099/TCP                     56d
pinot-broker-external       ClusterIP   IP               <none>        8099/TCP                     56d
pinot-broker-headless       ClusterIP   None             <none>        8099/TCP                     56d
pinot-controller            ClusterIP   IP               <none>        9000/TCP                     56d
pinot-controller-external   ClusterIP   IP               <none>        9000/TCP                     56d
pinot-controller-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        9000/TCP                     56d
pinot-server                ClusterIP   IP               <none>        8098/TCP,80/TCP              56d
pinot-server-headless       ClusterIP   None             <none>        8098/TCP,80/TCP              56d
pinot-zookeeper             ClusterIP   IP               <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   56d
pinot-zookeeper-headless    ClusterIP   None             <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   56
```

Can someone help me?